# How to change project->properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Debugging->Command Arguements using immediate or command window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

How to change current command and command line set in project properties using command line?
(with Immediate Window/ Command Window).

Best I have found out is:

> Project.Properties

Comment: You can't change command-line arguments with the intermediate window. Project Properties is what you're supposed to use.

Comment: That's not great :(. Especially I debug c++ command line application and leaving my keyboard is pain. Thanks @CodyGray.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't change it, Immediate Window often uses to display the values of variables in your code or others. For parsing c++ command-line arguments, you need to set it under the Project property.

Vote this request if other members also meet this issue:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/15555378-make-changing-command-line-simple

Comment: In immediate window: `>Project.Properties` opens Project Properties window. I was just wondering if would be able to even change command and command line either using _immediate window_ or _command window_.

Comment: It would have a limitation now, but it is a good feature request, https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/15555378-make-changing-command-line-simple, you could vote it, I have voted this user voice.

Comment: Yes I opened that request, @jack-zhai thanks a bunch for voting up :).

Comment: You are welcome:) I add the feature request to my previous answer, so other members who meet this question could help vote it